# How to add HTML class based on the contents of another element?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to add an HTML class to a particular element based on the content of another element. This element's data is dynamic. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="task_list col-lg-12 col-sm-12">

            @foreach($tasks as $task)

            <div id="{{ $task->id }}" class="row task_element">

                <p class="task_description">
                    {{ $task->description }}
                </p>

                <p class="task_priority">
                    {{ $task->priority }}
                </p>

            </div>

            @endforeach

        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    if ($(".task_priority").text().trim() === "high") {
        $(".task_element").addClass('high');
    } elseif ($(".task_priority").text().trim() === "medium") {
        $(".task_element").addClass('medium');
    } else ($(".task_priority").text().trim() === "low") {
        $(".task_element").addClass('low');

</script>
```

This is currently not working. It seems like a simple task, but I have not been able to find out how to solve it. How do I add a class to the "task_element" div based on the text value of "task_priority"?

Comment: I would try wrapping it in an onload function to make sure its executing after the document is loaded `window.onload = function() { your code
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 tasks with for example high low medium

```
$(".task_priority").text().trim()
```

will return highlowmedium as string

Your last else statement doesn't start with an if and the statement doesn't close.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.task_element').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).find(".task_priority").text().trim() === "high") {
        $(element).addClass('high');
    } else if ($(element).find(".task_priority").text().trim() === "medium") {
        $(element).addClass('medium');
    } else if ($(element).find(".task_priority").text().trim() === "low") {
        $(element).addClass('low');
    }
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gfbh0yg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your js code inside [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

From the docs:

> $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Your code becomes

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($(".task_priority").text().trim() === "high") {
        $(".task_element").addClass('high');
    } elseif ($(".task_priority").text().trim() === "medium") {
        $(".task_element").addClass('medium');
    } else ($(".task_priority").text().trim() === "low") {
        $(".task_element").addClass('low');
});
```